# Multiple source folders for Super Dev Mode

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

***Problem***
Is there any way [Codeserver](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html#Starting) accept more than one dir in the -src flag?

***Details***
I'm trying to separate my source code into folders like this:

- src
- widgets
- utility
- main

I got the regular dev mode to compile my code via the following *.gwt.xml files:

src/MyProject.gwt.xml

```
<module>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name="com.my.project.Widget"/>
    <entry-point class="com.my.project.Test" />
</module>
```

widgets/Widgets.gwt.xml

```
<module>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name="com.my.project.Widgets"/>
</module>
```

But every time I try to run in the Codeserver (SuperDevMode), it will say it can't find classes in com.my.project.Widgets package.

I'm running SuperDevMode using the following arguments:

```
-src src/ com.my.Project.MyProject
```

But I'm guessing I need something like:

```
-src src/ com.my.Project.MyProject widgets/ com.my.Project.Widgets
```

***FYI***
I know you can organize the classes using packages but I would prefer to have them in separate source folders, so later on I can easily repackage them into separate jars.

***Update***
Just tried adding the [module]:

```
-src src/ com.my.Project.MyProject com.my.Project.Widgets
```

Didn't work :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass `-src` as many times as you need it:

```
-src src/ -src widgets/
```

The modules comes last on the command line, and are looked up in all source folders and the classpath:

```
-src src/ -src widgets/ com.my.Project.MyProject
```

Note that only modules with an `<entry-point>` (or inheriting a module that has an `<entry-point>`) can be passed that way on the command line; without entry-point the module is only a "library" to be inherited by other modules, not an "application".

Note, you could also just add all your source folders to the classpath, instead of using `-src`.

Comment: Thanks I had a feeling I was being dumb. Using -src widgets/ com.myProject.Widgets worked. But I'm a little confused about the second part of your answer: "Note that only modules with an <entry-point>...". Are you saying that my Widgets.gwt.xml file should also have a entry point? Cause right now it doesn't and its working.

Comment: And I'm using eclipse so the widgets folder should have already been added to the classpath? At least in the various configuration windows, I'm seeing my folder being added...

Comment: Oh nvm I was being dumb just read you answer again. I was under the impression that "-src src/ com.my.Project.MyProject" was one argument lol. Not two separate argument.

Comment: Re. `<entry-point>`, I was saying that you shouldn't pass Widgets as argument given that it has no entry point.